# Codeigniter Get php array from view

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter I have a view `theme-fonts.php` that I am loading in another view `page.php`.

`page.php`

```
<?php $this->load->view('theme-fonts'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try{
        var fontsArray = <?php json_encode($font_list); ?>;
        console.log(fontsArray);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
</script>
```

Following is the definition inside my `theme_fonts.php` file:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Denk+One" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Wendy+One" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet" />
<?php   
    $font_list = array();
    array_push($font_list,"Aclonica");
    array_push($font_list,"Michroma");
    array_push($font_list,"Paytone+One");
    array_push($font_list,"Denk+One");
    array_push($font_list,"Wendy+One");
    array_push($font_list,"Fjalla+One");
?>
```

So my question is how to access php array from view `theme-fonts.php` in main view `page.php`?

Regards: Jehanzeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after I solved the issue, I feel that it was a stupid question. As I am loading `theme-fonts` view inside `page` view and not in parallel. I can simply write my script code in `theme-fonts` view. This will in turn write it to my `page` view.

**page.php**

```
<?php $this->load->view('theme-fonts'); ?>
```

**theme-fonts.php**

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Denk+One" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Wendy+One" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet" />
<?php   
    $font_list = array();
    array_push($font_list,"Aclonica");
    array_push($font_list,"Michroma");
    array_push($font_list,"Paytone+One");
    array_push($font_list,"Denk+One");
    array_push($font_list,"Wendy+One");
    array_push($font_list,"Fjalla+One");
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try{
        var fontsArray = <?php print(json_encode($font_list)); ?>;
        console.log(fontsArray);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the array to your view:

`<?php $this->load->view('theme-fonts', array('font_list' => $font_list); ?>`

I suggest rather declaring the array in your controller and passing it to the main view, that way the array will be available in all the views you load.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. What I want is opposite to what you suggested. I want the array `$font_list` from `theme-fonts.php` to `page.php`

Comment: Why don't you declare the array in your controller and then pass it to the main view, that way it will be available for access in both `theme-fonts.php` and `page.php`. I'm not sure how you are structuring this but you can't load `page.php` and expect the array to be available if you haven't declared it yet.

Answer (score 0):

in MVC frameworks singleton class is available from everywhere, so you need store you variable to some property in your case the best place is config object,

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

[read about CI config](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html)